# Не работает find() для вложенного ключа MongoDB

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, mongoose

Структура БД:

```
name: value
type: value
categories: Array
    [0]: Object
         type: value
         name: value
    [1]: Object
         type: value
         name: value
```

Нужно найти все элементы, у которых в `categories` значение `name = 'TestCategory1'` или `'TestCategory2'`

Я использую Mongoose, вот мой запрос (не работает):

```
Media.find({ categories: { name: { $in: ['TestCategory1', 'TestCategory2'] } } })
```

Я не совсем разбираюсь в этих запросах, подскажите как его сформировать правильно.

Когда я ищу все элементы по конкретным значениям, я использую этот запрос, он работает:

```
Media.find({ categories: { '$all': [ { type: 'Image', name: 'TestCategory1' } ] } })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({
  "categories.name": {
    $in: [
      "TestCategory1",
      "TestCategory2"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UlihIMlNzcA)

Comment: спасибо, так просто, а я голову ломал)

Comment: Возможно, стоит дополнить ответ, что обращение по вложенным ключам происходит именно как `name.name`. А то как-то коротковато)